# Can I use plain CSS3 Animations in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Instead of using systems like `Animated` and `LayoutAnimation`, can I simply use CSS3 animations in styles(like in a normal web app), and is it recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to add animations to a `View` component.

The short answer is probably no, as there are no such style props mentioned in the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style) for applicable styles for View components.